# Windsor WCF Integration Facility Async

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, castle-windsor

I'm using Windsor WCF Integration Facility and am curently looking for a way to call a method asnyc. I was considering just using a background worker and doing the work on completion. Is there a more elegant way of doing this, i don't have a good feeling with selected way.

I've looked at the following email: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel/browse_thread/thread/9250110e258ccdcd from Krzysztof Koźmic. The solution seems great, it is however said it's just a prototype as i understand.

Answer (score 2):

[UPDATE] Since some time it is officially baked into the framework (with some changes) so it should be pretty safe to use at this point.

Yes, It's a prototype. I have created a working proof of concept implementation (without generating async type, just invocation and resolution so far), but it's still quite far from production quality, and I'm afraid it won't make it into the forthcoming release.

Recently I picked the work up again, and while I can't promise anything, it's high on my priority list :)

Comment: As we can see at google group post there just an interface with good idea about autogenerating Async interface and processing Expression<T> of call. Can we see some working prototype? And the question that I interesting in: why nobody tries to implement synchronious call in a new thread? is this incorrect for WCF calls?

And few words about proposed IAsyncClient interface. In my vision of async WCF calls there the point that I can use AsyncResult.WaihtHandle object to wait all async calls. In case of using callbacks I'll need to implement my own WaitEventHandles.

Comment: And despite the fact that Juval Lowy warns us not to use transactions with asynchronous calls, I think that it's necessary to implement a transactional asynchronous calls in WCF without generated proxy.